# Unable to cast COM object of type 'MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass'

Tags: .net, vb6, 64-bit, msscriptcontrol

Got this error when deploying a VB6 / .NET application on a 64-bit Windows 2008 machine.

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass' to 
interface type 'MSScriptControl.IScriptControl'. This operation failed because the 
QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{xxx}' failed 
due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT:
0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve, run the following command

RUN `CMD` AS ADMINISTRATOR

> regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSScript.ocx

Comment: Pretty crude, never just ignore corruption of the registry.  Find out first *why* it is corrupted before you start changing it and potentially do more damage.

Comment: I agree the answer could do with a bit more explaining. The solution remains the same though.